# How to use 'Join' and '& /@' : combining all .csv files in a directory into a single .csv file automatically

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import, automation, concatenation

I would like to import all .csv files in a directory and combine them into a single file using `Join`.  I can do this manually but when I try to automate it using `&/@` I run into problems.

The datafiles and example Mathematica notebook described in this question is available at this [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HKbfKDYsN99RLY6k_1mC02TTodn9Mx9U?usp=sharing)

**Details**

There are 7 files in the notebook directory, each with 6 header rows and ten rows of data.  (Each row has 8 columns).

I use the code below to do the following:

1. Search a directory for all file names containing ".csv"
2. Import them
3. Remove the header from each file.

```
root = NotebookDirectory[];

headerROWS = 6;
filenames = FileNames["*.csv", root];
files = Import[#] & /@ filenames;
files2 = Drop[#, headerROWS] & /@ files;
```

I verify that everything imported corrected as shown in screenshot below (7 files, each with 10 rows of data).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p65I.png]

**Stupid Manual Solution**
Using the same placeholder `#` and `Join`, it's straightforward but annoying to accomplish what I want manually:

```
MANUALjoin = 
 Join[files2[[1]], files2[[2]], files2[[3]], files2[[4]], files2[[5]], 
files2[[6]], files2[[7]]]; (*the dumb, manual way I want to avoid*)
```

The screenshot below shows this working as expected, i.e.: it simply concatenates the files while retaining the structure of the individual files.

[image]

**The Problem**
When I try to automate the `Join` operation using code analogous to the &/@ in the first block of code, it jumbles the placement of the rows. This is what I've tried.

```
AUTOjoin = Join[#] & /@ files2;  (*Fails *)
```

I see the following jumbled output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNNef.png]

It seems that `[#]` is somehow incompatible with `Join` but I don't see exactly how.  It seems that this code should be identical to the 'manual' version above.  Does someone see what the problem is exactly?

Comment: Try `Join @@ files2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join` is expecting a sequence, as you can see in your MANUALjoin.
You can convert your list of lists into a sequence of lists as follows:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
headerROWS = 6;
filenames = FileNames["*.csv"];
files = Import[#] & /@ filenames;
files2 = Drop[#, headerROWS] & /@ files;

autojoin = Join[Replace[files2, List -> Sequence, 1, Heads -> True]];
autojoin // TableForm
```

[image]

Incidentally, `Join[#] & /@ files2` is equivalent to `{Join[files2[[1]]],Join[files2[[2]]],...}`, not `Join[files2[[1]],files2[[2]],...]`

Comment: We could also write `autojoin = Catenate[files2];`.

Comment: @WReach, yes this is a better solution. Also `Flatten[files2, 1]`